# Exchange Soap Services 2010 Offline

Tags: exchangewebservices

Is it possible to call Exchange Soap Services 2010 offline if there is an exchange server setup?

Exchange Soap Services uses iOS application for Create Event View Event list.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is it possible to call Exchange Soap Services 2010 offline

No EWS is a Web Service so like any web service its a remote endpoint if your not online then there is no remote endpoint to process the request your sending. Your application or client could still function offline if you create your caching logic and retrieval logic but you won't be making the same EWS call as there would be no remote endpoint to process any responses.